# How to filter NSFetchedResultsController like "filteredArrayUsingPredicate"

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsarray, nspredicate

is it possible, to filter the results of a NSFetchedResultsController without a new call to the databaselayer, like I do it with an NSArray with "filteredArrayUsingPredicate"

Thanks

Comment: What's the question? You answered it yourself... `NSFetchedResultsController ` has the property `@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *fetchedObjects`, which is an array you can filter

Comment: thanks, if I use the NSFetchedResultsController in a TableViewControlle, how can I tell the NSFetchedResultsController to use the resulting NSArray instead of its own @property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *fetchedObjects for its methods like objectAtIndexPath

Answer (score 2):

You can set a predicate on the NSFetchRequest that you use to initialize your NSFetchedResultsController. For example:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    fetchRequest.entity = <YOUR ENTITY>

    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:<YOUR PREDICATE>];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:moc sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    // ...
```

You shouldn't need to "refresh" the fetched results controller since it should update as changes are made and saved. You may need to use the boilerplate code for using and/or updating a table view with a fetched results controller.

Comment: tnx. What I want to do is, filtering the result with different predicates (in memory) after it was fetched from the db. I think what you wrote would cause a new query to the databaselayer.

Comment: @mica you can filter in-memory arrays using predicates too, just user the filteredArrayUsingPredicate: method on NSArray.